# Flask-pymongo-mongodb. db.collection.drop() not working

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo-3.x

I'm trying to delete a collection in mongodb via pymongo,but its not deleting.Where did i go wrong? I have check in stackoverflow for different ways to delete a collection but its not working. Help please

```
code: https://pastebin.com/LEAJXvHP
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me to use **drop_collection (collection_name)** to remove collections.
(Python 2.7 and using pymongo)

Example:

```
mongoClient = MongoClient("xx.xx.xx.xx:27017")
db = mongoClient["DB_name"]
db.drop_collection ("collection_name")
```

I hope it helps you.
Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Beeing "mongo" the variable name that holds the instance of PyMongo, `mongo.db.drop_collection("collection_name")` should do the trick.